# Need to hide product loop on home page woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am using wordpress to build my new website. I have a custom plugin to show categories first, before the product loop. When the page loads, the categories (with pictures) are shown in 4 columns. Under that (and separate from it) the normal product loop begins with 4 columns. I would like to hide the product loop but ONLY on the home landing page. I just want to see the categories there. Is there a code snippet I can add to do that?

Here is my site (under development)
www.puddlekickers.com

Thank you!
Karen

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site 
that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once 
the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that 
demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see 
[Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) 
Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am asking for code that I do not currently have. I would like the code to hide the product loop but only if it is on the home landing page. I included the link to my site to show how the site functions now. There is no error on my site, it is just displaying the products on the landing page which I would like to remove. 

What meaningful code would you like me to include? I will be happy to include it. Thank you.

Comment: Is there some option in your theme? Perhaps some extension to disable it? Explore your theme option is your best bet now.

Comment: There is no option in the theme because a plugin is used to list the categories. Here is the last part of the code from the plugin:

add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop', 'puddlekickers_product_subcategories', 50 );

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quickest and dirtiest way would be with CSS. This would hide the product loop before the page is loaded.

```
body.home ul.products {
    display: none;
}
```